# SSIS loop using dates and ODBC source SQL Server target

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying use SSIS/SSDT to sync a PostgreSQL source view into a SQL Server target table. I have the initial sync working after a lot of trail n error.

The issue I'm having is I want to use an out loop to limit the scope of the Data Flow to sync on day at the a time.

I have the loop increasing the date by 1 fine.

The expression I'm using for the ODBC Source (PostgreSQL) is as follows

```
"SELECT * from usage r 
where 
start_time >= '" + ((DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yyyy", @[User::PeriodStart]) + "-" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm", @[User::PeriodStart]) + "-" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd", @[User::PeriodStart]))
+ "'
and start_time < ('" + ((DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yyyy", @[User::PeriodStart]) + "-" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm", @[User::PeriodStart]) + "-" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd", @[User::PeriodStart]))
+ "'::date  + INTERVAL '1 day')
and r.chargeable=true 
AND r.start_time > '2000-01-01T12:00:00' 
order by r.start_time asc"
```

The @[User::PeriodStart] is only evaluated once and isn't updated each time its loops.

I'm sure this is simple but my google skills with SSIS is failing

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It fixed it self. not sure what I did.